# SQL Server Query: How to return the percentage value of specific records over the sum of values of many records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had trouble phrasing the title of the question, but hopefully with the illustration tables below, it will be easier to understand the query I'm trying to perform. I've researched the OVER (Partition BY) options but haven't been able to get them to work.

I have the following source table with the desired query results that I'm trying to write:

[image]

Essentially I'm trying to calculate and return the percentage of 'Y' value from the source table for each combination of col1 with col2. So in the illustration above looking at the first two records only, the value of Y is 3 and the total for Foxtrot is 13 which yields 0.230769.

Is there a simple way to write this query without having to use one or more CTEs? From reading about the Over() expression I thought I was getting close but could not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select col1, col2,
       sum(case when col3 = 'Y' then col4 else 0.0 end) / sum(col4)
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Note the `0.0`.  This ensure that the result does not rely on integer division.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and concise response. I upvoted your answer but since I don't have enough responses on this forum it registered it, but does not display it I was told.